# how to call same function by ajax response alink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

a-link is working in index.php. But if a-link comes from ajax response the A-link is not working I want to call same function by response a-link. here my full code.  please explain with full code.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        function SelRej(){ 
        var SRvalue = $(this).attr("value");
        //alert(SRvalue);

        var URL = "Ajax.php";
        $("#"+SRvalue).load(URL, {
            "SRvalue":SRvalue
            });

        if(SRvalue=="Reject"){$("#Select").html("<a href='#' class='Select' value='Select'>Select</a>");}
        if(SRvalue=="Select"){$("#Reject").html("<a href='#' class='Reject' value='Reject'>Reject</a>");}
        return false;
        }

        $(".Select").on('click', SelRej);
        $(".Reject").on('click', SelRej);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Select"><a href='#' class='Select' value="Select">Select</a></div>
<div id="Reject"><a href='#' class='Reject' value="Reject">Reject</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax.php

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["SRvalue"] ){

   $SRvalue = $_REQUEST['SRvalue'];
   if($SRvalue=="Select"){echo "Selected";}
   if($SRvalue=="Reject"){echo "Rejected";}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's it I was looking for

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

         function SelRej(){ 
             var SRvalue = $(this).attr("value");//alert(SRvalue);
             $.ajax({
              url: "Ajax1.php",
              cache: false,
              method: "GET",
              data: {SRvalue: SRvalue}
                }).done(function(response) {
              var splitted = response.split("|"); 
              $("#Select").html(splitted[0]); //alert(splitted[0]);
              $("#Reject").html(splitted[1]); //alert(splitted[1]);
            });
         }
            //$(".Select").on('click', SelRej);
            //$(".Reject").on('click', SelRej);

          $("body").on('click', ".Select", SelRej);
          $("body").on('click', ".Reject", SelRej);


    });
    </script>
    </`head`>
    <body>
    <div id="Select"><a href='#' class='Select' value="Select">Select</a></div>
    <div id="Reject"><a href='#' class='Reject' value="Reject">Reject</a></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ajax1.php

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["SRvalue"] ){

   $SRvalue = $_REQUEST['SRvalue'];
   if($SRvalue=="Select")
   {
    echo "Selected|<a href='#' class='Reject' value='Reject'>Reject</a>";
    }

else if($SRvalue=="Reject")
   {
   echo "<a href='#' class='Select' value='Select'>Select</a>|Rejected"; 
     }
}

?>
```